# SVD for theoretically singular matrix -- any way to improve solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, error-propagation, singularity

I'm trying to solve a linear system such as $Ax = b$. This is related to a measurement system I'm working on and the nature of the equations is such that $A$ is singular in the absence of errors.

When I use made up perfect data with no errors, I can solve the system using an SVD and get the exact correct answer. However, when I use real measurement data, which has a good amount of error in it, the solution is further off then it should be.

My understanding is that because my matrix is highly singular errors are magnified. Is there any way I can improve this or is this the best I can expect given the circumstances?

**EDIT:** The matrix is always larger than a $4 \times 4$ and its rank is always 4 (if anyone cares).

**EDIT2:** *Context* -  The problem is related to a GPS system but I'm *not* using the conventional GPS solutions. $A$ is $n \times n$ with n being the number of satellites in view. The problem is fully defined with $n = 4$ since there are four unknowns. It becomes overdefined for more than four satellites. Because of the errors in the signals from each satellite, a choice of only four gives a poor estimate, so the goal is to solve the overdefined problem to achieve better accuracy. That is where I'm running into this issue.

Comment: Is your matrix always square ?

Comment: If you have a $n \times n$ matrix with rank 4 and $n$ much larger than $4$, it is not strange that you are getting far away from the solution.

Comment: Yes, it is always square. It also has zeros on the main diagonal and is symmetric.

Comment: Could you explain the context of your problem and why, in ârticular, you have this condition rank=4. It might give an indication...

Comment: @JeanMarie $n$ is often between 8-10.

Comment: @JeanMarie I edited the question to add some context.

Comment: One way to attack the problem is "incremental'. I mean by that 1) add to the first four constraints a fifth constraint chosen among the remaining ones, and do that for all remaining constraints and see which one has the smaller variation (considered for example with Frobenius norm). 2) Aggregate this constraint to the 4 first. 3) Then repeat (do the same thing by adding a sixth constraint with the augmented  4+1 system of constraints)...

Comment: @JeanMarie Would you consider adding this as an answer and maybe explaining a bit more. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by seeing which has the smaller variation and how to check that with the Frobenius norm. Thanks.

Comment: I have given my indication as a more detailled answer.

Comment: @littleO I mentioned in the comments that it is a square matrix. It is also symmetric and has zeros on the main diagonal. When I say "overdefined" I don't mean that it becomes a rectangular matrix. It stays square, just becomes bigger. This *is not* the conventional GPS solution.

Comment: @Hadi sorry I misunderstood, I'm deleting my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

One way to attack the problem is "incremental'. I mean by that

1) Add to the first four constraints a fifth constraint chosen among the remaining ones. Thus, for the resulting  new $5 \times 5$ matrix, obtain its singular values and compute a measure $m$ of perturbation of the set of the first four ones, for example

$$m=\sum_{k=1}^4 |\sigma_k/s - \sigma'_k/s'| \ \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ \ m=\sum_{k=1}^4 (\sigma_k/s - \sigma'_k/s')^2$$

where $\sigma_k$ is for the $4 \times 4$ matrix, and $\sigma'_k$ is for the $5 \times 5$ matrix ($\sigma'_5$ is not considered), and $s$ (resp $s'$) is the sum of the $\sigma_k$ (resp.  $\sigma'_k$ ).

2) Do that for all remaining constraints

3) Keep the constraint (i.e., its matrix) that has the smaller $m$ (i.e., is the more coherent with the previous measures).

4) Then repeat (do the same thing by adding a sixth constraint with the augmented 4+1 system of constraints)...

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. This looks promising.